# Exception thrown at 0x00091021 in Lab14.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00124000

Tags: assembly, x86, visual-studio-2019, x86-16, masm

I'm getting Exception thrown on **mov ax, num[si]** after **loop 1**. It shows that "***Exception thrown at 0x00091021 in Lab14.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00124000***". What does this mean? how can I fix it?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, deExitCode:DWORD

.data
num dw 1111h, 2222h,3333h, 4444h
len dw ($-num)/2
res dw 0000h

.code
main PROC
mov ax, ds
mov ds, ax
mov si, 00h
mov cx, len

loop1:
mov ax, num[si]
L1:
add si, 02h
add ax, num[si]
Loop L1
mov res, ax
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

    

    ;INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: The first statement in `main` looks like a typo. Did you mean `mov ax,cs`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - "mov ax, ds" means "mov ax, @data"

Comment: You are creating a Windows application using 16-bit real mode code. That isn't going to work.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - I was asked to code using 16 bits unsigned integer..

Comment: @MichaelPetch - the question was .. "write a recursive procedure in assembly language that take an 16 bits unsigned integer, n as input, such as if n=4, it computes 1+2+3+4"

Comment: "Takes a 16-bit unsigned integer" is completely different from "is entirely 16-bit code".

Comment: `int 21h` is also going to fail, if you fix your code to use 32-bit pointers.  Also, you claim that "mov ax, ds" means "mov ax, @data".  But that's not plausible; `ds` is a valid register name.  It would make no sense for MASM to take a valid asm source instruction (`mov ax, ds`) and turn it into something else.  I know MASM is crazy weird sometimes, but that seems like something nobody would ever want.  If you want `mov ax, @data`, write `mov ax, @data`.  (Or since you're building it as 32-bit `.model flat,` code, don't mess with segment regs!!)

Comment: The loop does 1 iteration too many! You are adding 5 numbers and thus reading past the array.